# How do I use CAS (compare and set) operation

Tags: aleagpu

How can I read-modify-write the same variable from multiple GPU threads? In C++AMP I used the standard lib's compare-and-set function, but I haven't found an example in AleaGPU.

I know the goal is to avoid such things, but without getting into much detail I'll say its pretty necessary for my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API in AleaGPU: http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/api/html/64c9ca47-2e8e-265b-d968-15345e374320.htm

The usage is described here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomiccas